# php header() function problem about download file

Tags: php, file, download

I have a file download function in my website. it works fine before. but after we moved the site to another server with runs PHP 5 (it runs on PHP 4 before). when click to download, it automatically adds a extra blank line at the beginning and the end of the file which we don't want to. Here is the code for downloading function:

```
header("Content-Type: application/gas");
header("Cache-control: private");    
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=aaa.gas");
```

Could anyone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: perhaps printing file content instead of Content-Disposition header would help?

Comment: Off topic: The RFC 2231 standard states you should surround your `filename` in double quotes. If you were to try and provide a `filename` that has a space in it, the download will not play nice in Firefox. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download

Comment: The given code doesn't actually print the output, nor does it show the PHP open/close tags. It's clear that this question is missing a pertinent testcase, and without one it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 4):

There may be an extra blank line after the `?>` that closes the PHP within the script. [Exit the script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) after sending the file in order to prevent this from mattering.

Comment: Or simply don't close your PHP tag. There's usually no need to.

Comment: For the love of God, please *always* close your PHP tags. That's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: This comment of mine is redundant, but it's so VERY important, so here we go: @MichaelIrigoyen **must** be listened to here!

Comment: @Tomalak. If a file contains only PHP, and is not a HTML template, it should open with `<?php` and have no closing tag. There's no call for one. All it does is introduce the possibility of this error.

Comment: @TRiG: And look horrible. I guess I can't really come up with any practical downside to it, which is frustrating, but I heavily disagree with getting into this habit. It just seems messy and dangerous somehow.

Comment: thanks guys! I have <?php and ?> nicely paired there. and I am trying to put quotes around filename now. I don't understand what Shyboycha suggested. any one can explain please?

Comment: no luck!guys. still got extra blank line at the beginning of the text file. any more idea? thanks.